# How do i get a usable int for a switch statement from a void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

The parameter 'opt' is passed to my function with pthread_create:

```
intptr_t num1 = 0;
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &routine, &num1)
```

and then I have a switch statement in my function that will print one of two statements depending on the case:

```
void* routine(void* opt) {
    long int n = (long int)&opt;
    switch(n) {
    case 0: 
        printf("Test 0 from threads\n");
        break;
    case 1: 
        printf("Test 1 from threads\n");
        break;
    };
    sleep(3);
    printf("Ending thread...\n");

    return NULL;
}
```

That first line of the function is where I'm stuck. I'm trying to get the original value of num1 into 'n' so that I can use it for the switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fix the problem, you can change the line

```
long int n = (long int)&opt;
```

to:

```
long int n = *(intptr_t*)opt;
```

However, this does not seem like the proper solution. The following code does not seem ideal:

```
intptr_t num1 = 0;
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &routine, &num1)
```

It does not seem appropriate to use the type `intptr_t` (which is designed to hold pointer values as integers) in this case, if, as demonstrated in the question, you only want it to store the values `0` or `1`.

You could of course simply use `int` or `long int` instead of the data type `intptr_t`. But I suspect that you selected the data type `intptr_t` to be able to directly store the value inside a pointer, like this:

```
intptr_t num1 = 0;
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &routine, (void*)num1 );
```

If you do that, then, in the function `routine`, you can use the line

```
long int n = (intptr_t)opt;
```

to convert the pointer back to a number.

The first solution has the disadvantage that you must ensure that the [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) of the referenced object has not expired, whenever you dereference the pointer. This is not a problem with the second solution.

Comment: Or much better, `uintptr_t`

Answer (score 3):

The original value you're passing in is a `intptr_t *`, so that's what you should be reading it as.

```
intptr_t *n = opt;
switch(*n) {
```

Answer (score 3):

`routine` doesn't use the argument in a way that demands the integer be passed by reference at all.  That is, you're only using the value of the integer.  Since you're already using an `intptr_t`, you can take advantage of the fact that `inptr_t`s can be safely converted to pointers and back.

```c
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, routine, (void*)num1);
```

```c
void *routine(void *opt)
{
    intptr_t n = (intptr_t)opt;
    ...
}
```

A benefit of this approach is, since you're passing the integer by value, you won't run into a problem if the original variable falls out of scope.

Comment: I take your point - I did not notice the change to the `create` call.